# How to create a histogram with echarts

Tags: reactjs, echarts

How can I create a simple histogram with apache echarts? I checked their documentation and it does not appear there. Does echarts not have histogram?

Comment: If it's not in their documentation, it seems likely that it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Echarts tools with datasets

Echarts [data transformation](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/data-transform/) can be used to shape a dataset into a histogram dataset, using `'ecStat:histogram'`.  Here is a [very good example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-histogram) showing how to use this tool. You can also find a clear [documentation](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-stat#histogram) on github.

This solution is a bit more complex to handle (understanding [datasets](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/concepts/dataset/#dataset) and data transform) but it's the clean way to make a histogram.

### Simple hand made solution

You can create a chart that looks like a histogram using Bar charts. Your data will need some formatting so that it looks like a list of `[x,y]` :

- x : (rangeMax - rangeMin)/2
- y : number of points in that range

You are also going to need to set `barWidth` to 100% and `xAxis.type` to 'value' for it to look like a histogram.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'bar',
      barWidth: '100%',
      data: [[5,20], [15,52], [25,200], [35,334], [45,390], [55,330], [65,220]]
    }
  ]
};

myChart .setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```